# Visual Studio 2017 remote code synchronization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, synchronization

I've been developing a c++ project on linux remote server these days, however, I'd like to do all the coding things on my windows machine using VS2017. So I need  some kind of synchronization tool to synchronize the codes such that whenever I save the file in VS2017 the changes can be synchronized to the linux server immediately. Is there any tool or VS2017 extension can help me?

I don't want to use git as it may cause a lot meaningless commits.

Comment: Why don't you just use git, but work within a branch that isn't master.  Then just do a pull request and/or squashed merge whenever you have a "meaningful commit".  That way, your commit history on master won't have the superfluous commits you meant for testing.

Comment: @selbie, because my project has many complex dependencies and I have to debug my program on linux server, so if I use git, after each very tiny modification, I will have to type many git commands to synchronize it manually. It is very inefficient.

Comment: I typically share workspace folder with linux. So I don't need to perform any sync at all.

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas:

1. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com).  Compile your code on the emulated Linux/Unix environment for local testing and use Visual Studio as your IDE.  Do final testing on the Linux box with less frequency.  Can be combined with any of the ideas below.
2. Git, but with a different branch for commits. Do a squashed merged for all meaningful commits or pull requests to master.
3. Samba.  Mount your Linux file system on your Windows PC or vice versa.  Copy files between Windows and Linux as if was a network drive.
4. Local VM.  Run Linux in a local Virtual Machine with VMWare or VirtualBox.  Drag and drop files between Windows host and Linux guest OS using the host/guest extensions stuff.  Then you can dink around with deploying to the real Linux machine later.

Personally, for my open source projects where I'm too lazy to boot into Linux locally to test code before deploying to AWS, I basically do some combination with the above.

And #5 of course is: Dropbox.  :(  I use OneDrive and a Python script on Linux to pull down files.